# How to display a specific string for a Null items and another string for a zero-length string

Tags: ms-access, vba

At the table object level, I created a short text field.

I know you can use the Format property to format text one way and Null/zero-length strings another way. e.g. `@;"N/A"`

However, how could I change this so that I display `TBD` for Null items, and `N/A` for zero-length strings?

I've tried all sorts of expressions but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: What are the all sorts of expressions you've tried and what results did you get?

Comment: Well, first I tried using a combination of the IIF and ISNULL functions as part of the second section of the Format property:
@;IIF(ISNULL([Text]), "NULL","N/A")
But is this even possible? Can you use an expression in the Format property???

Comment: No, the field's format property does not accept functions.

Comment: Is this field only for display (i.e read only), or does it need to remain editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Format property, but an expression will do, not in the table but where you present the values, for example as the *ControlSource* for a textbox:

```
=IIf([YourField]="","N/A",Nz([YourField],"TBD"))
```

The trick is, that `[YourField]=""` returns *Null* if the field is Null, which makes `IIf` to returns its *False* part where `Nz` takes care of the rest.

Answer (score -4):

You can create an aux Column to display the right value , for example

=IF(I10="Null","TBD",IF(I10="","N/A",I10))

[image: Table example]

Comment: That's for Excel, not Access.